# Installing Wordpress on IIS 7 - invalid root password or failed to connect

Tags: wordpress, iis, web-platform-installer

I'm 100% sure the user/pass are correct.

Screenshot: [MYSQL command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izV5z.jpg)

Screenshot: [WebPlatform Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRvka.jpg)

i've tried all the suggested workaround but none avail

- deleting mysql_pwd from registry (HKCU/Software/Microsoft/WebPlatformInstaller/mysql_pwd)
- installing latest mysql connector (6.9.9)

the other suggested way is to delete the folder path for mysql on my drive which I dont want to as i have existing data from my current database (MYSQL 5.7)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you created a non-root user and tested with it? I would do that anyway for INFOSEC reasons. My two cents: get the site onto a Linux VM. https://roots.io/trellis